# Scraping data from a webpage using xpath in python, selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm new to coding so I apologize for any novice mistakes.

I'm looking to scrape data from a webpage using python and selenium. I think that I've identified the xpath for the data I'm looking to extract, but when I extract it, it returns "None" instead of returning the data.

I am trying to pull "Oct 2001 - Jan 2002" from the following html:

```
<h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>Oct 2001 – Jan 2002</span>
    </h4>
```

To do so, I've run the following code:

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
prev = sel.xpath('.//span[@class = "pv-entity__date-range.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal"][1]').extract_first()
print(prev)
```

Which outputs:

```
None
```

How can I identify "Oct 2001 - Jan 2002" from this bit of html?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sel = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
prev = sel.xpath('.//span[contains(.,"Dates Employed")]/following-sibling::span').extract_first()
print(prev)
```

---

EDIT: To get a text, you can do:

```
prev = sel.xpath('.//span[contains(.,"Dates Employed")]/following-sibling::span/text()').get()

print(prev)
```

Comment: That worked! It returns "<span>Oct 2001 - Jan 2002</span>", how could I strip the <span> and </span> so that it is only the data? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately - returns this error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'" - Gonna try just slicing the first 6 characters and last 7 characters from the string unless you have a better idea. Thank you again

Comment: Slicing works - it's choppy and there's probably a more efficient solution but this will work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To print the span[2] value you can do.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("h4.pv-entity__date-range.t-14.t-black--light.t-normal>span:nth-child(2)")
print(elem.text)
```